# OpenGL ES 2.0 on iPhone - How many texture units can i use?

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es

In apple's docs:(http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/OpenGLESPlatforms/OpenGLESPlatforms.html)

it says that for "OpenGL ES 1.1 on the PowerVR SGX" "There are 8 texture units available."

it doesn't say how many units are available on OpenGL ES 2.0, does that mean there is no limit?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rather than asking and getting an answer that may or may not be correct in the future, your app should be checking programmatically at runtime using something like this:

```
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS, &MaxTextureUnits);
```

Note that there are also separate numbers for the number of allowed texture units in a vertex shader and a fragment shader. They would use the constants `GL_MAX_VERTEX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS` and `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS`. The `COMBINED` number is the number available to both at the same time.

Comment: GL_MAX_TEXTURE_UNITS is not defined on gl.h iOS

Comment: Sorry - in ES 2.0, it's `GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS`.

Comment: Actually there is `GL_MAX_VERTEX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS`, and `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS` and `GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS` enums. First is for count texture units of allowed for usage in vertex shader, second one is for fragment shader, and third is combined for both shaders combined.

Answer (score 2):

There is a detailed listing of all the hardware across iPhones and iPads on Apple's [iOS Device Compatibility Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/OpenGLESPlatforms/OpenGLESPlatforms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013599-CH106-SW1)

Based on this, you are safe with using upto **8** **Texture units** on *any* iOS device.

Comment: Useful answer - good to know the *minimum* expected, not just an arbitrary number at runtime, since it can affect the core design of our shaders.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the answer is in same page you linked in question:

> OpenGL ES 2.0 on the PowerVR SGX
>
> Limits
>
> ...
>
> **You can use up to 8 textures in a fragment shader. You cannot use texture lookups in a vertex shader.**
>
> ....

Comment: "You can use up to 8 textures in a fragment shader." is not the same as max texture units. i can use more than 1 fragment shader.

Comment: what if i use 2 fragment shaders? can i load into memory 16 texture units?